# 'React-Native-Share' Library fails to compile on Web

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, syntax-error

I've been creating react-native app to share text or images to social platforms.
I've used [React-Native-Share](https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share) library to serve the purpose of my application.
This library is working fine for iOS & Android but when I'm running it on Web.
I'm facing compiling failed error (Syntax Error). It seems like React-Native-Web cannot parse the syntax used by this library.
As far as I researched on it. I think I need to setup webpack.config.js for this to work, but as I've never did this before so not sure how it works and how to set it up.

Please see the attached screenshot
[Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqd1Z.png)

Thank you in advance :)